# How are you meant to declare a Dependency Property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I was reading a tutorial on how to make a parametrized style ([here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/)). In it, it uses some dependency properties. It declares them as such:

```
public static Brush GetTickBrush(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (Brush)obj.GetValue(TickBrushProperty);
}
public static void SetTickBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
{
    obj.SetValue(TickBrushProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TickBrushProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "TickBrush",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(ThemeProperties),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));
```

Now, as I like snippets, I went ahead and looked for one, to see if I didn't have to make one. There was one, but in a completely different style:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

Now, what I don't get: what's the difference between these two? Why does one need a `DependencyObject` to get the value while the other one doesn't? Do you use them in separate scenarios?

Comment: They are the same except for their usage is different. The first method uses static methods so it would allow to set a controls value using syntax like: Control.GetTickBrush([InstanceOfTheControl]). The second method gives you access to the values via instance object. So you would have to do Control test = new control(); test.MyProperty to get or set the value.

Comment: @user2453734: They are *not* the same. Note that two different methods are used to register them.

Comment: Good catch, one is for a control and it has an attribute of type my property(second example). The second one is an attribute that can be applied to any control. It is not specific to a control. Let me see if i can find the proper terminology.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2010/06/25/understanding-wpf-dependency-property-and-attached-property.aspx is a good example of what the difference is between a dependency property and an attached dependency property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first example you show is for an [*attached property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), which is a special kind of a dependency property. Values of attached properties can be "attached" to other objects, while usual dependency properties belong to the instances of their respective class.

The second code snippet shows a regular dependency property and is the way to go if you just want to add an additional dependency property to a custom class you are creating.